# How to show details initially in Dired mode?

Tags: dired

windows 10, emacs 26.1

Here dired in summary mode:

[image]

If I want to show detail I press `(` and here result:

[image]

Nice. But I want always to show dired in details.
So I set this variable:

```
 '(global-dired-hide-details-mode nil)
```

but it not help. It always show dired in summary mode.

Comment: The vanilla Emacs's Dired doesn't enable the buffer-local mode `dired-hide-details-mode` by default. So you need to figure out how you did it (a common way is `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-hide-details-mode)`) then undo it. And there is no `global-dired-hide-details-mode`.

Comment: Sorry it was because was start dired plus package. If disable it, then dired mode show , by default, show details info.

Answer (score 3):

As comments have indicated, in vanilla Emacs Dired does not hide details by default. But [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) does hide details by default.

If you want to use Dired+ and you want to show details by default then just customize option **`diredp-hide-details-initially-flag`**. That's what it's for: to give users control over the initial behavior.

---

See also option **`diredp-hide-details-propagate-flag`**:

> Non-`nil` means display the next Dired buffer the same way as the last.
>
> The last `dired-hide-details-mode` value set is used by the next Dired
> buffer created.