# How to not hide Dired details initially, with Dired+?

Tags: dired

I have GNU Emacs 27.2 (of 2021-11-18; on macOS 12.1) and updated `dired+.el` from [dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus)
just now (to fix a bug, so I can't go back to the old version of `dired+.el` I had). Before the update, `dired-mode` looked like this:

[image]

After the update, `dired-mode` looks like that:

[image]

I'd like to have the "long" format back. Specifying `(setq dired-listing-switches "ls -lh --time-style=long-iso")`
doesn't seem to affect the problem. How can I force a certain format with `dired+`?

Note that the original `dired+.el` which did not show this problem was version 21.2 (last updated 2013-01-28) and the current version is 2021.10.03 (last updated 2021-12-11).

**Update**

... just found that I can toggle the view with `(` (a change since Emacs 24 or so). The problems is also mentioned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44874/how-to-show-details-initially-in-dired-mode) and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920659/dired-not-showing-details-anymore). Neither solutions directly worked but setting

```
(setq diredp-hide-details-initially-flag nil)
(setq diredp-hide-details-propagate-flag nil)
```

after `(require 'dired+)` seems to work (any side-effects/better approach?)

Comment: Did you look at the variable `dired-listing-switches`?

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes, that shows `-al` as it should.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't read your question carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to edit your question, because it starts out saying one thing, suggesting that it's about `ls` changes, and ends up (correctly) saying another thing, which is that by default Dired+ hides details.

Anyway, the answer to your question is what you discovered just this:

```lisp
(setq diredp-hide-details-initially-flag nil)
```

(But as a general rule it's better to use `M-x customize-option` or `customize-set-variable` than to use `setq`.  In this case it doesn't matter.)

You don't need to change option `diredp-hide-details-propagate-flag` for your question.  That's something different.  That's about whether you want the subsequent (new) Dired buffers to use the same detail-hide/show behavior as the last one.

---

BTW, the beginning of your question kind of threw me off, as I was mistakenly getting the impression that you updated from a fairly recent version of Dired+.  In fact, you must have updated from a very old version.

Also, just `(` is enough to toggle hiding details.  `M-x (` doesn't do that.  (There's no command `(`, at least not in Dired+.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Drew, also for updating my post.

Comment: Just to add: The one-line solution that Drew provided only worked for me if it was put *before* `(require 'dired+)` (otherwise only the two-line solution in my Update worked).